# A 6-sided dice is rolled and M is the result obtained, then a coin is thrown M times and the number of heads obtained is N.

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, dice

My question is how to determine the conditional probability $\mathbb{P}(N=2|M=4)$, I'm trying to do it, but i didn't figure it out how to determine $\mathbb{P}(N=2 \cap M=4)$, and another question, how can I determine $\mathbb{P}(M=i)$, where $i$ is between $1$ and $6$? I thought that any probability $\mathbb{P}(M=i)$ would be $1/6$, but is it really this?

Thanks in advance,
Fernando

Answer (score 1):

If the dice is a regular one, then $\mathbb{P}(M=i)=1/6$, you are correct. Then, assuming $M$ is fixed, $N$ follows a binomial distribution of parameters $p=0.5$ (for a regular coin) and $n=M$.

So, for any $0\leq j\leq i$, $i\in [\![1,6]\!]$,
$$\mathbb{P}(N=j | M=i) = \binom{i}{j}0.5^j\times 0.5^{i-j}$$

Comment: Thanks (I found the same probability, but without "see" the binomial distribution), another thing: Is it possible to find the conditional distribution of probabilities for M, given N (N=0, 1, 2,...,6)?

Comment: It should be, using Bayes Formula.

Comment: Another question, Florian. How can i achieve the formula P(N=j|M=i)?

Comment: What do you mean ? This is the formula written above.